# Understanding the proof of theorem 6.4 of Rudin's Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

In Rudin's functional analysis text I do not understand the following step in theorem 6.4 (a).

> $\phi -\phi _i \in (1- \delta _i ) W_i$

How do we get such delta? In particular how does $W_i$ being convex balanced set in $\mathcal D (\Omega)$ imply the existence of such $\delta$.
For reference I am attaching screenshot. Thanks in advance for the help.
[image]

Comment: Here there's a solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617738/doubt-in-the-proof-of-theorem-6-4-in-rudin-functional-analysis-1973?noredirect=1#comment9736388_4617738